# Xamarin.Essentials Screenshot.CaptureAsync() not working for video view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, screenshot, xamarin.essentials

I use this function to capture my video screen:

var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync ();

But the image created is not updated,
The view changes at runtime, and the image created is the initial image of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a try with **cleaning** the solution and removing all bin and obj folders,

Then **rebulding** it to check whether it works.